# React doesn't display images uploaded with Multer

Tags: node.js, express, multer

After uploading an image with Multer to the uploads folder which is located in the root with server folder and client folder, React cannot access the images in the uploads folder, as the api/upload route returns just a string as /uploads/the_image_name.

I thought I should upload the images to the public folder in the React folder but I found that the convention is using an uploads folder in the root.

Server :

```
app.use('/uploads', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/uploads')))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line should probably solve it:

```
app.use("/uploads", express.static('uploads'))
```

Comment: that actually works, What I did was app.use("uploads", express.static('/uploads')) but it didn't work now I see my mistake. thank you so much

Comment: I'm glad to hear that it was usefull

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually serve the images that reside in your `uploads` folder. One way to do this is to use the [express static middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html). Assuming your `uploads` folder resides in your app's root, you'd simply add to your express app:

```
app.use("/uploads", express.static('uploads'))
```

Comment: I had to add '/uploads' to app.use so that it worked. thank you

Comment: Ah right, little mistake. Would appreciate an upvote though as my answer explains what's going on ... :)

Comment: it does surely! thank you